# Firebase hosting seo friendly url

Tags: url-rewriting, firebase-hosting, http-redirect

I'm using firebase hosting for my blog
I use this

```
mydomain.com/?postid=how_to_etc
```

Method to get my post data
Is there any way to use SEO friendly url like,

```
mydomain.com/how_to_etc
```

So that this link should not redirect to 404 error page

Comment: I think you're looking to setup up a [redirect rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#redirects) or a [rewrite rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites) in your `firebase.json`.

Comment: Were you able to implement your solution by using redirect or rewrite rules? If that is the case, could you please post the solution as an answer and accept it? This increases the visibility for other users. If not, I will help you further with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of behavior requires rewrites configured with a single page app to interpret the URL path for its own router. this does depend on your current setup to determine the final work required.

alternatively, if you are using simple HTML; you can look at window.location properties and split the path with `split.("/")` to determine the path . See:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location